# Entire Database is Float and it's causing issues with reporting

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, selenium, csv

Skill level:  New to any programming but really determined to get my project done and learning all I can.  Not afraid to research.

Goal:
I'm not able to figure out how to connect to an API that I have to a Postgres database so I'm decided to use Selenium to mimic going into the portal and download the files and using python to import the .csv files into the postgres database so I can connect the data to my reporting software.

Not the best solution but I can't figure out how to get the data into postgres using python.  yet.. I'll get it but need a solution for now.

Expected/Actual Results:

Expected:  Script logs into web portal, downloads csv files, imports the .csv files into postgres
Actual:    Script is logging into this, it's downloading the csv files and importing the files into postgres, but I cannot figure out how to not make everything string and adding .0 to a lot of my "integer" fields.

error messages:
I'm not really getting error messages, but in the database when I create a report using tableau that everything is string and there are a lot of fields that have a .0.  Also the long and lat values are also string.

What I've tried -

I've been reading anything pandas related and I added the suggested df = pd.read_csv where the index_col=None but that doesn't seem to work.

```
    print("Printing csv present at " + file_path) # This takes the downloaded file and prints it to the csvs folder
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, low_memory=False, index_col=None, header=0)
    df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for c, x in enumerate(row):
            if isinstance(x, float):
                if math.isnan(x):
                    df.iloc[index, c] = 0
                else:
                    df.iloc[index, c] = int(x)
    return df
```

Below is my full script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import math
import time
import json
import sys
import csv
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import logging, traceback
from os.path import expanduser
import os,glob
import pandas as pd

startTime = datetime.now() #tracking the time it takes the script to run

# All credentials are housed in the user enviroment under the designated variable. 

cf_user = os.environ.get('CF_USER') # Windows Variable
cf_password = os.environ.get('CF_PASS') # Windows Variable

home = expanduser("~")
cf_url = 'subdomain.domain.com'

#directory where cf files are downloaded
directory = home + "/Downloads/"

def getDriver():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
    return driver

driver = getDriver()

def waitAndGetElement(delay, condition):
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(condition)
    return elem

def bulkDownload(url, file_format):
    driver.get(url)
    downloadBtn = waitAndGetElement(6000, EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[text()=" Download Now"]')))
    time.sleep(5)
    downloadBtn.click()
    current_url = url = driver.current_url
    export_num = current_url.split("/")[-1]

    file_path = file_format.format(export_num)
    while not os.path.exists(file_path):
        time.sleep(2)
    
    print("Printing csv present at " + file_path) # This takes the downloaded file and prints it to the csvs folder
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, low_memory=False, index_col=None, header=0)
    df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for c, x in enumerate(row):
            if isinstance(x, float):
                if math.isnan(x):
                    df.iloc[index, c] = 0
                else:
                    df.iloc[index, c] = int(x)
    return df

driver.get("https://" + cf_url + "/users/sign_in")
email_input = waitAndGetElement(300, EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user_email')))
email_input.send_keys(cf_user)
pwd_input = waitAndGetElement(300, EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user_password')))
pwd_input.send_keys(cf_password)

submit_btn = waitAndGetElement(300, EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="commit"]')))
submit_btn.click()

#ADDRESS_FILE_NAME_FORMAT = home + "/Downloads/address_export_{}.csv"
ORDER_FILE_NAME_FORMAT = home + "/Downloads/customer_export_{}.csv"
SIGNATURE_FILE_NAME_FORMAT = home + "/Downloads/signature_export_{}.csv"
PRODUCT_FILE_NAME_FORMAT = home + "/Downloads/product_export_{}.csv"

df = bulkDownload("https://" + cf_url + "/sub/file/area/products/export?model=product", PRODUCT_FILE_NAME_FORMAT)
df.to_csv('csvs/products.csv', index = False)

df = bulkDownload("https://" + cf_url + "/sub/file/area/signatures/export?filterrific%5Bsorted_by%5D=signed_at_desc&model=signature", SIGNATURE_FILE_NAME_FORMAT)
df.to_csv('csvs/signatures.csv', index = False)

df = bulkDownload("https://" + cf_url + "/sub/file/area/orders/export?filterrific%5Bsorted_by%5D=created_at_desc&model=customer", ORDER_FILE_NAME_FORMAT)
df.to_csv('csvs/customers.csv', index = False)

#df = bulkDownload("https://" + cf_url + "/sub/file/area/addresses/export?model=address", ADDRESS_FILE_NAME_FORMAT)
#df.to_csv('csvs/address.csv', index = False)



driver.quit()

# The below section grabs any .csv file in the 
# csvs folder and imports it to the designated postgres database.  
# Any excel file housed in the folder with multiple sheets will be imported as it's own table.

import psycopg2
import os
import glob
import csv
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

db_user = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
db_password = os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
db_name = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')

conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password, host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")

conn.autocommit = True

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
         WHERE table_schema = 'public'""")

allTables = []
for table in cursor.fetchall():
    allTables.append(table[0])

for WorkingFile in os.listdir('csvs'):
    if os.path.isfile(WorkingFile):
        xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile(WorkingFile)

createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ( {} )" #Any csv file housed in the csv folder will be turned into a table.
colName = "{} VARCHAR(20000), "


# use pip install xlrd==1.2.0
for i in os.listdir('csvs'):
    if i.endswith('xls') or i.endswith('xlsx'):
        file_name = os.path.join('csvs', i)
        name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)
        all_workseets = workbook.sheet_names()
        for sheet in all_workseets:
            worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet)
            worksheetfilename = f"{name}_{sheet}.csv"
            csvPath = os.path.join( worksheetfilename)
            with open(csvPath, 'w+') as csvFile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                for j in range(worksheet.nrows):
                    writer.writerow([str(entry) for entry in worksheet.row_values(j)])

for i in os.listdir('csvs'):
    if not os.path.splitext(i)[1].endswith(".csv"):
        continue
    table_name = os.path.splitext(i)[0].replace(' ','')
    print(table_name + " table has been created.")
    cols = None
    with open(os.path.join('csvs', i), encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        columns = next(reader)
        csv_cols = []
        for j in columns:
            if  '"' in j:
                j = j.replace('"','')
            j = f"{j}"
            csv_cols.append(j)
    cursor.execute(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_name}") # If the table exists it will drop and readd the table with the new data

    with open(os.path.join('csvs', i), encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        cols = next(reader)
        
    tableCommands = ""
    

    cols = list(set(cols))
    for j in cols:
        if  '"' in j:
            j = j.replace('"','')
        j = f"\"{j}\""
        # print(i)
        tableCommands += colName.format(j)
    tableCommands = tableCommands [:-2]
    command = createTable.format(table_name, tableCommands)


    cursor.execute(command)

    insertCommand = "INSERT INTO {} {} VALUES {}"

    with open(os.path.join('csvs',i), encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            # print(row)
            row = (','.join(["'" + str(r).replace("'", "''") + "'" for r in row]))
            # print(row)
            cols_ = [f"\"{c}\"" for c in csv_cols]
            command = insertCommand.format(table_name, str(tuple(cols_)).replace('\'',''), '(' + row + ')')
            # print(command)
            cursor.execute(command)


# Deletes all files with the extension .csv from eht directory variable
files_in_directory = os.listdir(directory)
filtered_files = [file for file in files_in_directory if file.endswith(".csv")]
for file in filtered_files:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(directory, file)
    os.remove(path_to_file)
print("Files have been removed successfully")

cursor.close()
print(datetime.now() - startTime) #displays the time it takes the script to run - at the end.
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot for a beginner!  To address the heart of the question, all the data in the CSV is text and you'll have to know what kind of data/type it is and convert that column-by-column, row-by-row. Since you got the web/download stuff working, can you extract the part of your code that's working on the CSV file, and also paste in some sample CSV? Try to focus on opening a CSV file and getting that into PostrgreSQL: I see lots of loops over CSV files, but focus on a CSV file, let's get that working. What does that code look like? And share the error message.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is a lot of (don't want to post the links) .. but I did a LOT of tutorials trying to figure out what I needed to learn to do what I needed to do. I didn't know what I was looking for so it was hit and miss, but I'm getting there.  My entire script and sections are posted above.  the first snip is my actually csv read coding.